# How to pass username in kwargs of Django filter?

Tags: python, django, django-views, keyword-argument, django-2.1

In the webapp, to retrieve all the objects from a specific user I am using user pk. But to make url more readable I want to use username. The problem is in the django view, user pk in kwargs giving the correct values, but when I use username it shows error.

Here are my codes using 'username' as kwargs, that is returning keyerror,

views.py

```
class UserAllQuestionView(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'mechinpy/user_profile_question.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_all_questions'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(user=self.kwargs['username'])
```

urls.py

```
path('m/user/<str:slug>/questions/', views.UserAllQuestionView.as_view(), name='user_profile_question_all'),
```

html

```
 <a href="{% url 'mechinpy:user_profile_question_all' user.username %}">All User Questions</a>
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\Bidhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Bidhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Bidhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Bidhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Bidhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Bidhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
  142.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()

File "C:\Users\Bidhan\Desktop\Startup\mysite\mechinpy\views.py" in get_queryset
  454.         return Question.objects.filter(user=self.kwargs['username'])

Exception Type: KeyError at /m/user/bidhan/questions/
Exception Value: 'username'
```

Comment: please add whole error traceback

Comment: why `<str:slug>` ?

Comment: @sky_1 I have added traceback, as I can not add add image now, I have edited the question.

Comment: @BearBrown I use str to pass all the char of the username, for ex- phil.65 , when I use slug:slug, it omits the dot.

Comment: `user_profile_question_all` has one parameter: `slug`, not `username`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mismatch in URL parameter names

Given I understand your question correctly, you pass the username as a slug to the view, like:

```
path(
    'm/user/<str:slug>/questions/',
    views.UserAllQuestionView.as_view(),
    name='user_profile_question_all'
),
```

You name this parameter `slug` however, but in your view, you call `self.kwargs['username']`. You thus need to change one of the two. For example:

```
path(
    'm/user/<str:username>/questions/',
    views.UserAllQuestionView.as_view(),
    name='user_profile_question_all'
),
```

Furthermore it will probably still not work. If I understand it correctly, your `Question` class has a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model. A `User` is not the same as its textual representation (for example by means of a `username`), so the filter will look like:

```
class UserAllQuestionView(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'mechinpy/user_profile_question.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_all_questions'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(user__username=self.kwargs['username'])
```

## Using the `user_id` instead

That being said, it might be better to user the `id` of the `User` instead, which will likely introduce less confusion (for example what if a user manages to use a username with a slash in it, then the URL will no longer work). So a more safe approach might be:

```
path(
    'm/user/<int:userid>/questions/',
    views.UserAllQuestionView.as_view(),
    name='user_profile_question_all'
),
```

```
class UserAllQuestionView(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'mechinpy/user_profile_question.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_all_questions'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(user_id=self.kwargs['userid'])
```

and in the template write it like:

```
<a href="{% url 'mechinpy:user_profile_question_all' userid=user.id %}">All User Questions</a>
```

Comment: So the url mismatch returning me an error, I have changed <str:username> instead of <str:slug>, now getting the desired output. Thank you.